# unresolved reference: openRawResource

Tags: reference

I'm trying to use a Trust Manager for Https Connection with a self-signed certificate. Part of my code would consist of loading the certificate from a raw file, but I get the error

Would anybody help me please?

Kotlin plugin version: 1.3.41-release-Studio3.4-1

```
            // Load CAs from an InputStream
            val cf: CertificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509")
            val caInput: InputStream = Resources.openRawResource(R.raw.srvca3)

            val ca: X509Certificate = caInput.use {
                cf.generateCertificate(it) as X509Certificate
            }

            val keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType()
            val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType).apply {
                load(null, null)
                setCertificateEntry("ca", ca)
            }
```

...

Unresolved reference: openRawResource

Answer (score 1):

Is this Resources the android.content.res.Resources class? Then openRawResource(int) is instance method, not static method there. You need to have some instance (an object) of Resources type to call the method on it. Like:

```
fun yourFun(resources1: Resources) { // Pass it.
     var resources2: Resources = ... // Or create it.
     resources1.openRawResource(R.raw.srvca3)
}
```

**Answer like this from this link.**

> https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/resources-openrawresource-unresolved-reference/13689/2

Or

check Is R file path correct :)